# UITableView: Scroll and swipe gestures are disabled after taping/updating and deleting a row probably in iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView which is programmed like this:

1. When a cell is tapped, labels in the cell are updated.
2. When a cell is swiped to the left, a "DELETE" action is shown.
   (The program uses tableView(:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath))
3. When the "DELETE" action is tapped, the cell is deleted.
   (tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(:, withRowAnimation:) is used)

**QUESTION**
When I tap and delete cells very quickly, sometimes scroll and swipe gestures of the table view are disabled after the row is deleted.
(But the tap gestures of the cells are still working.)

This happens with my iPhone 5S / iOS 10.
Xcode version 7.3.
I can't make this happen in iPhone 6 Plus / iOS 9.

I guess this is iOS 10's bug.

Does anyone know how to fix it or work around?

Will it be fixed if I upgrade my Xcode to Xcode 8?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to refresh tableview?

Then move the tableview to its original location .

Comment: Do you mean I create UITableView object again then scroll every time a row is deleted?